# Cannot read property 'directive' of undefined in Wijmo grid

Tags: angular, wijmo5

I am using wijmo grid of version `Wijmo 5.20163.234` and

> It was working fine `angular 2.2.1` before upgrading to `angular 2.3.0`.

Now getting error, if I am using **grid** with `wj-flex-grid-column` directive:

```
<wj-flex-grid [itemsSource]="data" [isReadOnly]="true" [headersVisibility]="'Column'" [selectionMode]="'ListBox'">
    <wj-flex-grid-column [header]="'Name'" [binding]="'name'"></wj-flex-grid-column>
    <wj-flex-grid-column [header]="'In Use'" [binding]="'inUse'"></wj-flex-grid-column>
    <wj-flex-grid-column [header]="'Order'" [binding]="'order'"></wj-flex-grid-column>
</wj-flex-grid>
```

Error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property ‘directive’ of undefined
```

But it's working fine without **directive** `wj-flex-grid-column`:

```
<wj-flex-grid [itemsSource]="data" [isReadOnly]="true" [headersVisibility]="'Column'" [selectionMode]="'ListBox'"></wj-flex-grid>
```

I tried to see core `grid` file and seen **directive**, it's there but it's working at all.

Please help someone if we have to explicitly something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got solution, I had to updated `Wijmo` version. I upgraded from `Wijmo 5.20163.234` to `Wijmo 5.20163.240` Now again It's working fine :)

Comment: Where did you get that? I'm currently using the eval version and I can only download 234...

Comment: Our client bought and we requested for updated version and got this from `wijmo` support. We are using `paid version`.

Comment: Okay thanks for the quick reply, that's unfortunate I was trying to evaluate wijmo for our company, but that just got a lot harder...